# How to connect Dynamics 365 CRM with MuleSoft?

Tags: dynamics-crm, mulesoft

As the title says, I'm having trouble connecting to Dynamics CRM 365 from MuleSoft.

I'm not sure do I need to setup something else on the Dynamics part for it to work.

This is my connector:

```
admin@2xxxx1.onmicrosoft.com
password: password from admin@2xxxx1.onmicrosoft.com account
resource: https://org6b123456.crm4.dynamics.com/
client id: Azure client ID after you create the connected app
client secret: Generated from Azure
Token request endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant from auze/oauth2/token
```

Generated secret, gave permission to crm, can connect from postman and yet I can't connect from mule.

I get :

> org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Failed establishing connection with Dynamics 365 API

Is there some extra step what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Upon just reviewing the error snippet shared by you, it doesn't have enough information to pinpoint the specific cause of the error.

It's recommended to enable debug logs for the Microsoft Dynamics 365 connector, which will provide detailed logging information. In order to do so, kindly follow the article [How to Enable Wire Logging for Microsoft Dynamics 365 Connector on Mule 4](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-Wire-Logging-for-Microsoft-Dynamics-365-Connector-on-Mule-4)

Furthermore, I came across a MuleSoft meetup that featured a demonstration of [integrating MuleSoft with Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM](https://meetups.mulesoft.com/events/details/mulesoft-indore-presents-indore-mulesoft-meetup-5-integration-with-microsoft-dynamics-365-crm/), I encourage you to explore its content.

Additionally, there's a comprehensive [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/GRSn8TRi6Z4?si=YfR0QEBwvQAsEwKR) linked which could also offer valuable insights.